# How to modify erts modules

Tags: erlang, loader

I want to modify the module erl_prim_loader, but I found that it didn't take effect. 
This file does not seem to be loaded from `$ERL_ROOT/lib/erts-10.1/ebin/erl_prim_loader.beam`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a preloaded module, so there is an extra step to make modifications take effect.  From [a message by John Högberg to erlang-questions on 2019-04-29](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2019-April/097829.html):

> `prim_file` is a prebuilt module that's statically embedded into the
>   emulator, and the emulator crashes if there are any problems
>   initializing it. In this case you've added a function to the NIF but
>   haven't yet rebuilt the module, so it crashes when trying to inject the
>   non-existent `my_truncate_nif/1`.
>
> To update these prebuilt modules, you need to run:
>
> ```
> ./otp_build update_preloaded --no-commit
> ```
>
> Try doing this on a clean build without changes to the NIF (C code),
>   and then rebuild the emulator with the changes applied. Note that you
>   will need to rebuild the emulator every time you update the preloaded
>   modules for the changes to take effect.
>
> Hope that helps!

Comment: ok, great..  It's work. I update preload modules and reinstall. Thank you very much!